# Behavior I don't understand in bash

Tags: bash

I have a folder with 3 dummy files: ab0, ab1 and ab2.

```
$ echo ab*
ab0 ab1 ab2

$ myvariable=ab*
$ echo $myvariable
ab0 ab1 ab2

$ echo 'ab*'
ab*
```

Up to here, I think I understand. But:

```
$ myvariable='ab*'
$ echo $myvariable
ab0 ab1 ab2
```

I was expecting `ab*`. This means that there is a basic that I don't understand.

I've been searching for single vs double quotes, expansion and more in bash tutorials and manuals but I don't get it yet.

Comment: Also try `echo "$myvariable"`

Comment: This might help you understand: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/intro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line `$ echo $myvariable` is being parsed by first substituting the contents of `$myvariable` into the line, then running the line.  So when the line is parsed by bash, it looks like `$ echo ab*`.

If you `$ echo "$myvariable"`, you will get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

BASH isn't performing the expansion during the assignment, its expanding when you run the `echo` command. So with both kinds of quotes, you are storing the raw string `ab*` to your variable. To see this behaviour in action, use quotes when you `echo` as well:

```
hephaestus:foo james$ echo ab*
ab0 ab1 ab2
hephaestus:foo james$ var=ab*
hephaestus:foo james$ echo $var
ab0 ab1 ab2
hephaestus:foo james$ echo "$var"
ab*
hephaestus:foo james$ var='ab*'
hephaestus:foo james$ echo $var
ab0 ab1 ab2
hephaestus:foo james$ echo "$var"
ab*
hephaestus:foo james$
```